# IF function or AND function In MS Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
    Per FUEL
Conversion Bracket  <35%     35.01 to 40.00   40.01 to 44.99      >45%
< 76%                 0            10               15             20
>76.01 % < 80.99%    25            30               35             40
>81% < 85.99%        30            35               40             45
> 86%                35            40               45             50

Conversion2   Quality Scores    ANSWER      
38.46%               89%            
43.10%               97%            
39.13%               99%            
50.00%               92%            
51.28%               92%
```

I want any `IF` or `AND` function in the cell `I9`, which can reflect a result from the above grid.

Let's say conversion is between `50.01 to 40.00` and Quality is `81 to 85.99`, then the result should be 35.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a sample workbook. Use a file sharing service like dropbox or skydrive. If you cannot post a url as a new user, post the url as plain text. Experienced users will know how to deal with that.

Comment: Your conversion table does not make sense. It starts with 38, then 43 then 39 then 50. What is the logic in the order here? Also, the conversion bracket table does not make sense. There are values of <35 to >45 in the columns and <76 to >86 in the rows. But how do I place a value of 50 in that table?

Comment: Your conversion bracket `50.01 to 40.00` and quality range `81 to 85.99` can't be found in your reference table. Did you perhaps mean conversion bracket `35.01 to 40.00`?